# How to block hardware Back button and re-login again

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have implemented below navigation for my app which has login and logout feature.
How to block hardware Back button and re-login again. Below is the flow:

1) Login page is the MainPage when App launch

MainPage = new Login();

2)  After successfully login, user will be navigated to MainMenu Page

NavigationPage NP = new NavigationPage(new MainMenu()); 
 App.current.MainPage = Np;

**In MainMenu:**

1) How to I override the Hardware button for iOS and Android (but iOS has no Back Button in current ipad and iphone).

```
This is what I got so far to stop back button.

protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{          
     base.OnBackButtonPressed();

     return false

}
```

1a) How to detect if device is iOS and Android phone? Since iOS has no back Button, will onBackButtonPressed() apply to it?

1b)  will putting return false before or after base.OnBackButtonPressed(), make a difference?

2) User logout

in the beginning: Login -> MainMenu:   in MainMenu page, user click Logout button

```
 void LogoutButton()
 {
   Navigate.PopModalAsync(new Login());
 }
```

will this cause any problem since the first time login, MainPage is App.current.MainPage = Np;

Now what is the Mainpage = ??  when user click Logout button?

What happen when user login again? Which Navigation method I should use to go back to Login Page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that asking multiple questions at once isn't really according to the StackOverflow guidelines. To answer your questions:

> 1) How to I override the Hardware button for iOS and Android (but iOS
>   has no Back Button in current ipad and iphone).

The method you're overriding does indeed stop the **hardware** back button. It does not however stop every method a user has to go back. What you could do instead is create a separate Activity for your login and decorate that with the following:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp",
          Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher",
          MainLauncher = true,
          NoHistory = true,
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
          ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class LoginActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity { }
```

The `NoHistory = true` part is the interesting one. This means it won't be included in the Android navigation stack so you can't go back to it using the back buttons.

> 1a) How to detect if device is iOS and Android phone? Since iOS has no
>   back Button, will onBackButtonPressed() apply to it?

No. `OnBackButtonPressed` does nothing on iOS. It will not be called.

> 2) User logout in the beginning: Login -> MainMenu: in MainMenu page,
>   user click Logout button will this cause any problem since the first
>   time login, Now what is the Mainpage?? when user click Logout button?
>   What happen when user login again? Which Navigation method I should
>   use to go back to Login Page?

You can swap out the `MainPage` as needed. This will also help you when it comes to the back button. On app startup you can check if the user is logged in already. If he is, you set the `Current.MainPage` to your main menu page. If not you set it to the login page. When the user has successfully logged in you set the Current.MainPage to the main menu page. Since you set the main page, you get a completely new navigation stack, so the back button will not make the app go back to the login page.

Comment: 10Q and appreciate your kind help.  Case(1): Login -> Successful and goto -> MainMenu (with no stopping back Btn code implemented), when user press back button, it wont go to Login page instead the app close or exit. Is this normal? When login OK, I use NavigationPage NP= new NavigationPage(new MainMenu()) ,mainPage= NP.  So When user click back button, the app has no idea which stack to use to pop out the last Page. is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's expected behaviour. When there's nothing else to go back to the app closes instead. When the login is successful you create a new navigation stack. This means that every page you push onto that will be able to be popped using the back button. But when you get to the MainMenu page you can't pop any further so the app will probably close.

Comment: Please consider marking this as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: I certainly will. let me do some testing and I will come back here. Thank for your kind help. I hope this will help others who are in search for this solution.